# Gnome 3.8.1 Missing entries in Settings

Tags: gnome

So I installed Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome and updated Gnome-shell to 3.8. Current version is 3.8.1.

I decided to edit what applications show in the lock screen when, to my amazement, no privacy entry appears in the Settings area.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You *"updated Gnome-Shell to 3.8"* probably using the [GNOME3 Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3). But GNOME is more than Shell and consists in multiple packages, many of which are updated by the PPA (just use the dropdown menu to filter *"Published in"* to **"Raring"** and click filter).

You'll see that currently this PPA provides `gnome-shell 3.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1.2`, but you'll also see that there is no `gnome-control-center` entry. This is because the Ubuntu GNOME Team is still working on [integrating Gnome Control Center 3.8.x](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-gnome-3-8). Which means you just have what ships with vanilla Ubuntu, which is 3.6 and which doesn't have the Privacy module you are looking for.

Your two options are:

1. To wait for the development to finish (then when it's ready it will arrive from the PPA as an update).
2. To try the **unstable / WIP / will break your system** development version through the [GNOME3 Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging) (very unrecommended unless on a test machine you are ready to break)